# Issue converting project visual studio 2008 to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

so I have downloaded a template from the tutorial website http://devmaster.net/posts/introduction-to-c-with-game-development-part-2-project-template
however I have a problem because the template was apparently made in Visual Studio 2008, and I have Visual Studio 2010. When I convert the project I get the error "Unable to start program'C:\c++\Debug\Template.exe' The system cannot find the file specified."

I looked in the original file before conversion and the \Debug\Template.exe file does exist, however after converting the file it gets deleted. I had a few warnings on my conversion and I found this:

"MSB8012: $(TargetPath) ('C:\c++\Debug\Template.exe') does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value 'Template_debug.exe' ('C:\c++\Template_debug.exe') in project configuration 'Debug|Win32'."

Any idea how to fix this?

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a fresh project in Visual Studio 2010 and adding the source files and dependencies. Then compile and run, always works!